# Can I manufacture US1434590?

Tags: us1434590

In reference to the patent: [US1434590](https://www.google.com/patents/US1434590)

Can I re-invent this somehow? I thought it was an old antique metal ring back in the 1800's. What is the deal with this patent?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. I'm unsure of what you're trying to ask here. I understand you have some questions about the listed patent, but are you curious of the status of the patent (expired/not expired), what it covered, whether you could *re-patent* it, or something else? I would appreciate if you could [edit] your question a bit to be a little more specific. Please let me know if I can help with that process.

Comment: exactly what you said yes, the status expirer etc what it covers, yes all that would be good info thank you.

Comment: Does it simplify your question to know that it is expired? See ["How do you determine a patent expiration date?"](/q/3801)

Comment: We definitely want to get your questions all answered; I'm just asking in case this all ultimately boils down to concern over infringing.

Comment: ok i don't really know what infinging means sorry, but the post above .... what did you mean by 'it is expired' does this mean it hasnt got a patent anymore ?

Comment: i can't seem to figure out this calulator to find the terms, has it been expired this one do you know pls ?

Comment: Patents grant an exclusive right--the patent holder is allowed to tell other people that they cannot perform whatever is *claimed* by the patent. However, that right *expires* after ~20 years. Since this patent is from the early 1920s, the owner would have likely stopped benefiting from it in the '40s.

Comment: i see i think i got the calculator right, it said expired 1941  ......  i think i'm good here thank you for now, i may get back to this conversation at a later date, thank you so much :) enjoy your day :)